# Objective C: Code freezes when loading series of images

Tags: objective-c, memory, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

My first post to the forums but I have been using answers posted here for the last several months and find the answers incredibly useful!  I'm still learning objective c and still learning some basics.

My code is several hundred lines right so I don't want to the post the whole code.  The basic premise of the code is to load a series of random images to random locations on the screen.

When I was trying to figure out how to deal with this idea I made a simple test version that would add one balloon when a button is pressed and then when you hit pop balloons delete all the balloon images that were created.

This balloon code worked just fine, and then I added this same concept into my main code.  However now when I use it only a larger scale the code would freeze at 99% cpu usage and 18.5 MB memory.  The code never failed but would sit frozen.  The larger version is basically just adding multiple balloons when a button is pressed instead of one.  Sometimes as many as 15 images.

Is there any reason a code of this style would not work on a larger scale?  Or how do you go about problem solving an issue when the code freezes and no error is given.

.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    // Holds an array of images of the balloons
    NSMutableArray *BalloonArray;

    // Holds an array file names of the balloon PNG files
    NSMutableArray *BalloonNames;
}

-(void)AddBalloon:(id)sender;
-(void)PopBalloons:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Allocates memory for the array
    BalloonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Allocates memory and inputs the names of the images
    BalloonNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pink.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"], nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)AddBalloon:(id)sender
{
    int x;  // x position of the balloon image created
    int y;  // y position of the balloon image created
    int i;  // Random index value to pull a random balloon image out

    // Random number generator for the x and y position
    x = arc4random_uniform(230) + 30;
    y = arc4random_uniform(400) + 150;

    // Random index value from 0 to 2
    // Random based on how many images there are to chose from
    i = arc4random_uniform(3);

    // Uses the image from the index value previously randomnized
    UIImage *Balloon = [BalloonNames objectAtIndex:i];

    // Places the UIImage in a UIImageView
    UIImageView *BalloonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:Balloon];

    // Sizes the image to the correct size
    BalloonView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 100);

    // Centers the image using the x and y coordinates
    BalloonView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);

    // Adds the image view to the view
    [self.view addSubview:BalloonView];

    // Adds the image view to the array
    [BalloonArray addObject:BalloonView];
}

-(void)PopBalloons:(id)sender
{
    // Removes each image in the array out of the main view
    for(UIImageView *Test in BalloonArray)
    {
        [Test removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // Removes all object from the array
    [BalloonArray removeAllObjects];
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you make sure you're not getting stuck in an infinite loop? What behavior causes the code to "freeze"? Can you post the code that calls the add balloon method? Side notes: variable and method names should start with a lowercase letter. Also, if "sender" is a UIButton, pass it in as a UIButton instead of id. id could be any object, which is obviously not safe. Another one, please do not use iVars, use properties. You can look up what properties are in the documentation (balloon array and balloon names should be properties).

Comment: Do yourself a favor and try to adhere to the usual coding conventions: method and variable names usually start with lowercase letters. That being said, where does it freeze? Did you break with the debugger and look where it was? How many subviews have you created and added?

Comment: I checked for infinite loops and "turned off" all the loops I could to check.  I don't believe it is infinite loop issue and checked every loop with line breaks.  I have very limited knowledge on objective c but I think it might be memory allocation issue.

Comment: Also, regarding coding conventions, avoid putting instance variables in the header. Either they're public, and they should be properties, or they're private, and they should be in a class extension in the .m (or better yet, private properties).

Comment: In my larger code it can create as many 15 images and then adds each as a subview.

Comment: Where is a good place learn about coding conventions?

Comment: I think first step is to see what the debugger can show you. Try this: when your app hangs, click pause in the debugger and examine which code is running at the moment.

Comment: It's out of the topic but you should consider read a [Programming with Objective-C: Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) in a free time. Because your coding style is not what objective-c developers like to read.

Comment: This is another good document on Objective-c coding conventions based on Apple and community guidelines: https://github.com/github/objective-c-conventions

Comment: @user3780458 -- You got a lot of comments on style, but the fact is there's nothing in the code that you posted will cause the app to freeze, so the problem is elsewhere in your code. I've written similar code for a game on iPad, and it works fine with 50-100 imageViews.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method `-(void)AddBalloon:(id)sender` to run on a Separate Thread. Perhaps you can use `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myThreadMainMethod:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];`. Have a look at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)

Comment: Bad idea. The `AddBalloon` method has UIKit calls in it, and all UIKit calls must be on the main thread. OP absolutely positively should ***NOT*** run `AddBalloon` on a separate thread.

Comment: @user3386109 Why is it a bad idea to perform heavy operations on a separate thread rather freezing the UI as described in the Question?Ofcourse UIKit calls can be made on main thread by PerfromSelectorOnMainThread when needed.

Comment: Yes, except the only heavy operations in `AddBalloon` *are* the UIKit calls.